# JS: Performance of Constructor using Key-Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, performance, constructor, associative-array, key-value

Are there any negative performance implications for using object literals *inside* of object constructors in JavaScript?

For example:

```
class Thingy {
    constructor(props) {
        if (!props) {
            props = {};
        }

        // defaults
        this.name = '';
        this.amount = 0;

        for (let key in props) {
            let value = props[key];

            switch (key) {
                case 'name':
                    this.name = value;
                    break;

                case 'amount':
                    this.amount = value;
                    break;

                ...

                default:
                    throw `Invalid property ${key}`;
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}

let thingy1 = new Thingy({
    name: 'The Thing',
    amount: 6
});

let thingy2 = new Thingy({
    amount: 4,
    name: 'Another Thing'
});
```

The idea is to make it easier to see what values are being attached to which properties as well as to be able to mix the order of properties passed (or even omit some), as opposed to the default method:

```
class Thingy {
    constructor(name, amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    ...
}

let thingy1 = new Thingy('The Thing', 6);
```

Obviously, this is a non-standard and more complex way of using constructors, but would it slow down performance?

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to check to see if any of the keys are invalid (and throw), and then just use `Object.assign`

Comment: You should never care about performance here. If you do (which you don't), use jsperf to answer your question. Unrelated, this looks like a bad pattern, and you don't need loops nor classes here.

Comment: It's a nicer pattern to use default args: `constructor(props={}) {/*...*/}`

Comment: Don't use a class for this. It makes consuming your api shit. Just use objects. No one wants to import and instantiate your behaviorless classes